# Rename ASP.NET Core's antiforgery cookie and maintain random part

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

ASP.NET Core's anti-forgery cookie name is `.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.XXX` where the last bit is random.

The cookie can be renamed like so:

```cs
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(x => x.Cookie.Name = "Foo");
```

But that will produce a cookie named `Foo` rather than `Foo.XXX`.

The options object has a field [AntiforgeryOptions.DefaultCookiePrefix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.antiforgery.antiforgeryoptions.defaultcookieprefix?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-antiforgery-antiforgeryoptions-defaultcookieprefix). Unfortunately it's `readonly`.

What is the purpose of the random substring (and is it really random or some sort of key?), and how can I rename the cookie so it still has that substring?

Comment: Here's the method that generates the "random" part of the cookie name: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/6a8083a9c4a6f28c21c8564e08d56bbe48e6b16b/src/Antiforgery/src/Internal/AntiforgeryOptionsSetup.cs#L32

Comment: Here’s a pretty old blog post exploring the unique suffix: https://blog.novanet.no/a-pile-of-anti-forgery-cookies You can probably do without it, it seems to be there to avoid collisions in case multiple applications run on the same domain?

Comment: @BenderBoy Thanks, that makes sense. Since it's created in a static method, it'll live for as long as the app, and on the next restart a new cookie name will be generated. So I assume I can create my own random substring in the same way and use it as in the code I showed above.

Comment: I don’t think it’ll be new on every restart. It’s basically a hash of the app’s executable path, so it should stay the same until you move it. Source explains it here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/6a8083a9c4a6f28c21c8564e08d56bbe48e6b16b/src/DataProtection/DataProtection/src/DataProtectionOptions.cs#L21 Forty layers deep, the identifier seems to come from here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/6a8083a9c4a6f28c21c8564e08d56bbe48e6b16b/src/DataProtection/DataProtection/src/Internal/HostingApplicationDiscriminator.cs#L30

Comment: @BenderBoy "Forty layers deep"... That should be funny but it's actually quite sad. The Identity middleware is a real PITA if you need to do anything that doesn't match the "getting started" docs perfectly. (And reading source code instead of documentation means my code is more brittle because they can change undocumented behaviour whenever they want and break my system.) Thanks for uncovering that info!